# font problem in miktex

Tags: fonts

I can not use the font MinionPro anymore, but have no idea what is wrong. The following code

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c = a + b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
Trying to make PK font MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa at 597 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa source file could not be found. Running     ttf2pk.exe...

)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa): Font MinionPro-Regula
r-Base-aa at 597 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

miktex-makepk: PK font MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa could not be created.
```

What is wrong here?
The filedatabase was recreated and I called `initexmf --mkmaps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no map entry for the font `MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa`. Did you enabled the map files of MinionPro? Informations about the map files can be found in the README:
 http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/README

Comment: updmap of miktex contains the line `Map MinionPro.map` and I called `initexmf --mkmaps`. The map is located at `C:\localtexmf\fonts\map\dvips\MinionPro`.

Comment: @Matthias: 1. check if the pdftex.map used by pdflatex contains the entries of the MinionPro.map. If yes check if one of this entries begins with `MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa`.

Comment: but that map file has no entry for `MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa`. So you have to find where the font is used.

Comment: I have reinstalled the fonts from ctan and called all scripts and placed all files where they belong. Now in my texlive installation, but the error remains the same.

Comment: @Herbert: There is such a file in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\tfm\adobe\MinionPro` (.tfm ending) and there is `base-MinionPro-aa.enc` in the `enc` folder.

Comment: @Matthias: Your problem is related to a missing `map`-entry, it has nothing to do with `tfm` or `enc`-files. This means that you either didn't enable the map-file correctly or used the wrong map-file (I can find the entry in the `minionpro.map` of `metrics-base.zip` but I didn't check the map-files in the other `zip`s). So do as I told you: check the map-files.

Comment: does the map file `C:\localtexmf\fonts\map\dvips\MinionPro.map` has an entry for that font? And do a `kpsewhich MinionPro.map` to be sure that you have the correct one, and controll if you have enabled by mistake another minion map file, e.g. minion.map

Comment: @Herbert: I have another minion.map, but that worked for years. The code on ctan contains only a single MinionPro.map in the file `metrics-base.zip`. That one does contain a line `MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa ...`. Could it be that I need to overwrite the settings? If I run `updmap --enable Map=MinionPro.map` nothing is done, because the map is already known (which could also be a wrong one). `kpsewhich MinionPro.map` finds the correct one.

Comment: Solved! I disabled the map file using `updmap --disable MinionPro.map` and then enabled it afterward. It now works